# Target [Laravel\Socialite\Contracts\Factory] is not instantiable. [Continue With Google]

Tags: laravel-5

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkRq7.png)

`[problem]`(https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTYnY.png)

`[.env]`(https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLLMc.png)

`[web.php]`(https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrQtX.png)

`[Controller]`(https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOwxA.png)

`When a user clicks on "Continue with Google," it opens the Google sign-up page, but an error is displayed. Everything appears to be in order, and I'm unsure why the error is occurring.`.
`[problem]`(https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTYnY.png)

Comment: Please add any code and errors you get as text, not as images.